# Android bottom navigation bar and tablets

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, bottomnavigationview

According to Material design guidelines, we should use left navigation instead of bottom navigation bar for tablets. I could not find orientation setting of layout in `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` as well as separate `LeftNavigationView`, so please tell me right way to implement left navigation bar for both tablets and phones. Should i write my own view for this instead of using `BottomNavigationView` from `design` library? Thanks in anvance.

[image]

Comment: Please star this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77688212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided to use the implementation of Iiro Krankka https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: For the record, this lib is deprecated, but still offers a bunch of things the official (as of April 2018) Google bar doesn’t do. Google I/O 2018 is around the corner, we’ll see.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `BottomNavigationView` does not meet tablet material design specification. Please open issue at b.android.com for missing feature.

Until then, I encourage you to try my [BottomNavigationLayout](https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/BottomNavigationLayout) or do some research for any other implementations out there.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice and try your implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Material Drawer Library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) and create navigation drawer very similar to gmail application solution. If you don't want use 3rd party library, the simplest way is create custom component.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the support of both `NavigationDrawer` and `LeftNavigation` for tablet.